# Подскажите как правильно соединять переменные с текстом

Tags: javascript

День добрый! Я в js не очень хорошо разбираюсь, столкнулся с динамической авторизацией ВК. Hе могу правильно задать путь после получения данных. Проверял на сайтах, пишет неправильный синтаксис. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
VK.Widgets.Auth("vk_auth", {width: "200px", onAuth: function(data) {
  location='http://ctfdev.ru?id_vk='+data['uid']+'&name='+data['first_name']+'&last_name='+data['last_name']+'&photo_big='+data['photo']+'&photo_mini='+data['uid']+'&hash='+data['hash']';
} });
```

Comment: Для того чтобы "соединять переменные с текстом" в es6 есть шаблонные строки (http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation), а в es5 да, чисто плюсиком.

Comment: когда неправильный синтаксис - консоль браузера, как минимум, показывает в чем именно эта ошибка заключается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в конце лишний знак '

> +data['hash']'

А вообще соединяют переменные с текстом знаком "+", как вы и сделали

```
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Auth("vk_auth", {width: "200px", onAuth: function(data) {
  location='http://ctfdev.ru?id_vk='+data['uid']+'&name='+data['first_name']+'&last_name='+data['last_name']+'&photo_big='+data['photo']+'&photo_mini='+data['uid']+'&hash='+data['hash'];
} });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил